# How to stop a singularity container instance from within

Tags: singularity-container

I want to design a Singularity instance that shuts itself down after some time. The background is that I always want to start an instance (`singularity instance start...`) when the user executes a command because the process in question (R) might start subprocesses and only if I have an instance, I can make sure that all started processes get terminated when the main process ends.

The instance will run a background process that regularly checks whether there are still processes running in the instance, and if not, should stop the container after some time. The way I could think of to stop an instance is `kill 1`, because a Singularity instance has its own PID namespace and PID 1 is a process called `sinit`, which adopts orphaned processes in the container and takes down all processes in the namespace if terminated.

The strange thing is that killing from a subprocess that is started automatically does not work if I kill it from a subprocess of the instance start script. `sinit` stays.

These are the things that do work (Singularity recipe file and command):

```
# (test1.def)
Bootstrap: Library
From: alpine:latest

%startscript
sleep 5
kill 1
-------------------------------------------
$ sudo singularity build test1.sif test1.def
$ singularity instance start test1.sif test1
```

This approach works: The Instance stops itself. But I cant use it because my timeout watcher
is a program written in Python, so it is a subprocess. Modelling this gives me a problem:

```
# (test2.def)
Bootstrap: Library
From: alpine:latest

%startscript
(
  sleep 5
  kill 1
)
-------------------------------------------
$ sudo singularity build test2.sif test2.def
$ singularity instance start test2.sif test2
```

Here I have the Problem: The Instance does not stop after 5 seconds.

This, however, works:

```
$ singularity instance start test2.sif test2  
$ singularity exec instance://test2 kill 1
# OK: Instance stops
```

What I need is the instance test2 stopping itself automatically, not only after I execute
the `kill` command manually using `singularity exec`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: if I am not wrong you want to stop the container using a Python code which you already have when you use `apptainer instance start`?

Comment: @PrakharSharma Yes, this is correct. The Python code will wait for some time after the instance was started and should stop the container if no programs are running in the container (besides the PIDs that always run, like PID 1 and the PID of the python code itself, of course)

Comment: Ok you need to run your python script in the environment section. here is a query I made when I was learning Apptainer. https://github.com/apptainer/apptainer/issues/663